# Google App indexing is not working

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I have added google app indexing to my android app. But it is showing partial.
To complete that I have tried updating the google play services, after updating google play services my Tracker is not working (Which I have used for google analytics). It is showing generate a new configuration file. So I am already using one configuration file , do I need to change with new configuration file?

Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance for your time

One more thing now it is showing to upgrade to google firebase services ? So do I need to use firebase?